# Stop and start gif animation in PictureBox by enabling and disabling it in mouse events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I added a gif to a PictureBox and when the form is loaded I disabled the PictureBox to stop playing the gif. Then when I hover cursor on PictureBox I would like to enable the PictureBox to start playing the gif, but it doesn't play the gif.

Why I cannot enable the PictureBox and play the gif on mouse hover and how can I solve this problem?

code:

```
private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Enabled = true;  
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: The Control is disabled, those events are not raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Receiving Mouse events for a disabled control**

When a control is disabled, mouse events will not be received by the control, instead they will be received by its parent.

So in this case you can handle `MouseHover` event of the parent and see if the mouse position is inside the bound of the `PictureBox`, then enable it.

For example. assuming the parent of the picture box is the form:

```
private void form1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Bounds.Contains(this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
    {
        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

**Stop or start gif animation in PictureBox**

In addition to disabling and enabling `PictureBox` to start or stop gif animation, another option for enabling or disabling the animation by invoking the [private void Animate(bool animate)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,1173) method:

```
void Animate(PictureBox pictureBox, bool animate)
{
    var animateMethod = typeof(PictureBox).GetMethod("Animate",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, new Type[] { typeof(bool) }, null);
    animateMethod.Invoke(pictureBox, new object[] { animate });
}
```

Then without disabling the control:

```
Animate(pictureBox1, true); //Start animation
Animate(pictureBox1, false); //Stop animation
```

Comment: @MustafaŞenelKargın Both solutions are tested and work properly. Make sure you have handled the events. If the PictureBox is directly on the Form, then you need to handle the Hover event of the form.

Comment: First one didn't worked but second one is worked thank you.