# Disabled Button not working on mouse Hover in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to enable a button on mouse hover. It is showing but it is flickering and the action it should perform when it's clicked are not working. Below is the code of the Mouse Hover event.

```
private void NewPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pan = sender as Panel;
    ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
    deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
    ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.White;

}
private void NewPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pan = sender as Panel;
    pan.Invalidate();
    ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
    deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
    pan.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

I have also added the Mouse Hovering event to the button. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Disable controls will not receive mouse events. Use event of the parent control.

Comment: Where is the enabling part actually? It already looks like you use the Mouse Events of a parent panel but i see only showing/hiding code for something that might be buttons.

Comment: @RezaAghaei can you please elaborate more on your solution? I didn’t quite get it

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Receiving Mouse events for a disabled control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691832/3110834).

Comment: You need to elaborate more about the problem that you are trying to solve; the layout of the form and how the controls are on it (maybe a screenshot of the form), the expected behavior, and ect.