# Stop mouse hovering events when typing in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a form where small panels are added automatically to the main panel. The panels change color when mouse hover over them but I added a function to search for specific panels that is creating an unhandled exeption error. Is there anyway to stop the mouse hovering event while typing?
Below is the code for the mouse hovering event:

```
        {
            Panel pan = sender as Panel;
            ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
            deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Show();
            ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.White;

        }

        private void NewPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pan = sender as Panel;
            pan.Invalidate();
            ModifyBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
            deleteBtn[resultPanels.IndexOf(pan)].Hide();
            pan.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same as your previous post [Disabled Button not working on mouse Hover in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72095594/205233) ?

Comment: You can disable events (using -=) before search and attach again (with +=) after the search.

Comment: Or just check in the events that a search is going on and then don't do anything in the events. Or better not everything. Because when you moved the mouse while searching then you will have missed some of the events and coloring/showing stuff will presumably be wrong then.

Comment: I think that @Victor has shared a very nice and simple solution to your problem. You can try it out. Thanks, Victor for sharing this as I never knew that we can disable events like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabled Button not working on mouse Hover in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095594/disabled-button-not-working-on-mouse-hover-in-c-sharp)